# number of positive integers n such that 1≤n≤2022 and n has an odd number of positive integer divisors?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $m$ be the number of positive integers n such that $1≤n≤2022$ and such that n has an odd number of positive divisors. Then what is the value of m?

My approach I have use fundamental thereom of arithmetic to write n as $$n=p_1^{a_1}p_2^{a_2}.....p_n^{a_n}$$
And put conditon such that $1≤n≤2022$ and each $a_i$ should be even so that tau n become odd.
I have gone for counting individually each n, with that property.
Is any short method for this?

Comment: Hi:) As you already said, if $n$ has an odd number of divisors, all $a_i$ have to be even. This means, that $n$ is the square of an integer. On the other hand, if $n$ is the square of an integer, then all $a_i$ are even. Hence, you just have to count all squares less than 2022.

Comment: Thankyou so much, I dull my mind in end

Comment: FYI - a simpler argument: any divisor $d$ of $n$ can be paired with $c = \frac nd$, another divisor of $n$. And since $d = \frac nc$, this pairing is unique. All the pairings with $c \ne d$ account for an even number of divisors. $c = d$ is possible only when $n$ is a perfect square, so only perfect squares have an odd number of divisors.